# Hierarchical queries on datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to create hierarchical queries on the App Engine.

My datastore have parents and children. Each parent has children. Imagine that I have to find children. I have a condition on the parent and an other on the children for example, imagine a real family datastore, my conditions are: I want all children that are a boy from parent who are 35 years old or more.

The query I have for now is something like:

```
P = Parent.query(Parent.age >= 35)
for p in P:
    C = Children.query(gender == "boy", ancestor = p.key)
    for c in C:
        -> here I print information on the children
```

But the query is very slow with a lot of parent and children to test. I want to avoid iteration like for etc. because I think it take a long time because of that! What is the best practice to have his kind of query but quickly?

I have also brothers for the children and I can make queries, for example if I want all children that have parent that are more that 35 yers old and a sister named "Sisi", I will have (each children have his brothers on the value "brother"):

```
 P = Parent.query(Parent.age >= 35)
        for p in P:
            C = Children.query(gender == "girl", name == "Sisi", ancestor = p.key)
            for c in C:
                C1 = Children.query(gender == "boy", brother == c.key, ancestor = p.key)
                for c1 in C1:
                    ->Here I print information about the children
```

In fact this example (family example) good for my project but it give an idea of the problem I have

Comment: I *think* you mean *query*, not *quest*. The only reference to Google App Engine and the word 'Quest' is related to the Google Android Play Games event service.

Comment: I've edited your question to be clearer, but I may have misunderstood what you were trying to do here. I *think* you want to do efficient hierarchical queries (where you have conditions on both the parent and the child nodes in a tree).

Comment: Yes sorry for my english ! Yes I'm trying to do efficient hierarchchal queries ! I edit the question !

Comment: How deep can your hierarchy be  or parent -> child -> child ?

Comment: No I have juste parent and children, but I can have brother and a condition on the brother... I edit the question to make an example of this case

Answer (score 1):

How I've been able to do this before is to store the keys in a separate lookup entity.  This goes along the key-value store premise that duplicate info is sometimes necessary for faster lookups.  For example:

```
ParentChildLookup
 - parent_key = ndb.KeyProperty()
 - child_key = ndb.KeyProperty()
```

You could even add a third dimension of you are getting grandchildren:

```
ParentChildLookup
 - parent_key = ndb.KeyProperty()
 - child_key = ndb.KeyProperty()
 - grandchildren_key = ndb.KeyProperty()
```

If you wanted to look everything up in a single query, you can add the repeated clause to make children and grandchildren a list:

```
ParentChildLookup
 - parent_key = ndb.KeyProperty()
 - child_key = ndb.KeyProperty(repeated=True)
 - grandchildren_key = ndb.KeyProperty(repeated=True)
```

You then need to insert/update these lookup values anytime there's a change in relationships.  The benefit of this is that you can avoid a lot of queries, specifically nested or multi-property queries.  If you don't like this approach, I would recommend taking a look at the "Relationship Model" explanation here:  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/modeling.  You can store the relationships between many-to-many objects without the need to store them all in the same entity.

Comment: Ok.. But what will the query be like if I would like a multi-property query ?

Comment: You need to do that in Python code, I would recommend taking a look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html.  If we are talking about 100 entities for children/grandchildren, it's faster to get them all by their keys (as stored in the lookup) and then process them using if conditions and other logic.  If you have more than 100 children/grandchildren, the above code wouldn't be any faster than a multi-property query.

Comment: If you are building something like ancestry.com with potentially billions of children, I would recommend looking at BigQuery:  https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/what-is-bigquery.  You can have App Engine export data to BigQuery, run all your batches of work, then App Engine can download the summarizations/aggregated data.